# How to assign awk result to an variable

Tags: shell, awk

I need to assign the following awk result to an variable. Please guide me how to do in shell script

```
awk -F: '$1=="{root}" {print $3}' /etc/passwd
```

Like

```
variable = `awk -F: '$1=="{root}" {print $3}' /etc/passwd`
```

But it wont work

Comment: Do you want to assign the **result** of the awk command (i.e. numeric success or fail value) or it's **output** (i.e. whatever string it prints, if any)? How would you do it for any other command? (hint - it makes no difference that the command in question here is awk)

Comment: Do NOT add space around `=`. But better than back tics, use parentheses, see Avinash post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to avoid spaces around the equal symbol. Since backticks are deprecated, you could put your code inside `$(..)` block.

```
variable=$(awk -F: '$1=="{root}" {print $3}' /etc/passwd)
```

Comment: I wonder if he REALLY wants `root` inside braces? Any passwd file I've seen wouldn't have that.

Comment: yep, i think he mean `awk -F: '$1=="root" {print $3}' /etc/passwd`

Comment: For the following, it not works for me
User=root
variable=$(awk -F: '$1=="${User}" {print $3}' /etc/passwd)
echo ${variable}

Comment: try `awk -v var="${User}" -F: '$1==var{print $3}' /etc/passwd`